# Move "across town" or "across the town"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, articles, determiners

> He moved ***across town*** to stay with his father.

Why don't we use "a" or "the" in these situations. As:

> He moved ***across the town*** to stay with his father.

Comment: There's a common theme to a lot of your questions--namely, *why do we casually omit some words from some sentences?*.  The answer is nearly always the same: *because we are lazy; and because decades of experience show us that we are almost always understood correctly without them*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*He moved across town* and *he moved across the town* can both be valid sentences, but they do not mean the same thing.

*Town* is a very old word and has numerous different uses, some which are countable, and some which are not. When used without an article, *town* usually refers to the population center where one is located, or which is nearest. This sense of town is not necessarily defined by any political subdivision or jurisdiction; it can simply mean an area which is more urbanized or more densely populated than the surrounding area, or of the civil population as distinguished from those associated with a university, military installation, or other large but closed community.

As [Macmillan has it](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/town):

> 2. [uncountable] the place that you live in, or the place that you are talking about
>
>    > He moved to another part of town.

I could live in a residential neighborhood of Washington, D.C. like [Cleveland Park](https://www.washingtonpost.com/realestate/neighborhood-profile-cleveland-park/2012/08/02/gJQA8TqmSX_story.html?utm_term=.3aa9fc69fcac), but still speak of *heading into town for a meeting*, meaning to travel to the central business district. This is entirely idiomatic even though Washington is a major city, not a town, and even if I am already starting out inside its geographic or political boundaries. A political candidate might be *coming to town* for a rally, and I might go to the other side *of town* to avoid crowds when he is *in town*, or I might get *out of town* altogether and visit friends in New York

This usage does not extend uniformly to other geographic terms. You can move *across country*, but someone on an international trip is *out of the country*, for example. *State* can sometimes be used in this way in the U.S., e.g. vacationing *out of state* or getting *in-state* tuition. But the zero article does not really work in this sense with *city*, *borough*, or *district*, among others.

---

*He moved across the town* is grammatical, but would be unusual to hear. I would probably interpret *move* as indicating some kind of motion, as opposed to relocation, and *the town* as referring to a specific political subdivision that has previously been referenced, rather than the place where I am. I imagine monitoring someone with a tracking device as he goes from district to district throughout the day.

*He moved across a town* is similarly grammatical, but would be even more unusual, and I cannot think of any reasons why one would say it. If there is a specific town in mind, you would say *the town*; if the town is unknown or unimportant, but you know it is a population center, you would say *town*.

Comment: Thank you. If a person is living in a real town, does he use "town" without articles?

Comment: As I noted, this sense of town is unrelated to whatever the local settlement is called or how it is classified or governed. If I move from the north end to the south end of the Town of Auburn, Massachusetts, then yes, I would still say I moved *across town*. If it's a fixed expression.

Answer (score 2):

They are very similar, but I'm going to try to find the differences (even if slight).

***across town*** would probably be used if the person being spoken to is familiar with which town you're speaking of, or maybe if you're speaking in a local sense. It's generally used with the town you live in.

***across the town*** would probably be used if you're speaking of a town which was previously mentioned and might not be the one which you live in.

***across a town*** would only make sense if you're not speaking of a specific town (as the article entails) but rather any town which could be traveled across.